# let tomcat deploy automaticly with a context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I have a project named 'projectx'. My goal is to execute `mvn clean install` and let *Tomcat* use the */target* folder to autodeploy the webapp.

I added *projectx.xml* with the following contents to */tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\Users\Username\workspace\projectx-webapp\target" path="/projectx-webapp"/>
```

I can see in the server log the file *projectx.xml* is processed succesfully.
The webapp is deployed successfully. The site url is *localhost:8080/projectx-webapp/* .However when I go to the url, the webapp is not found.

When I deploy the war file manually in *tomcat\webapps*, the webapp works fine when I go to the specified url. 
Did I missconfigure something in *projectx.xml*?

my *web.xml*:

```
<web-app id="projectx-webapp" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>Project Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my *pom.xml*:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>projectx</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectx-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectx-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Below declared dependencies are included for the servers who may complain about servlet/jstl missing dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>projectx-webapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You start tomcat after the command `mvn clean install`?

Comment: up and running ^^, but when I run 'mvn clean install' I don't see apache loading the war file :(

Comment: I've not understand sorry, You run tomcat when the /target/file.war exists or not?

Comment: (changed the original post a bit) The war file is present in the /target folder when tomcat is running

Comment: Tomcat deploy automatically all .war files inside the directory tomcat\webapps and keep this dir sync. The target directory you specified is not automatically deployed so the file.war must be into the dir you specify at the time of tomcat startup

Comment: I tried that as well, but I can see in the server log that Tomcat has actually unpacked and loaded the war. The url I go to just isn't working for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102140/discussion-between-andrea-catania-and-vjeetje).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have verified in the chat, your application are working well the problem is that the context used by the app was `/projectx` instead of `/projectx-webapp` that you expected.

This happened because for specify the deployment directory you has created the file `apache-tomcat-8.0.30\conf\Catalina\localhost\projectx.xml` when you has changed this to `apache-tomcat-8.0.30\conf\Catalina\localhost\projectx-webapp.xml` the app was deployed with the context you expected `/projectx-webapp`